# pushout in the category of topological space is closed under product with compact set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, compactness

Assume we have the following pushout, where $X_0, X_1, X_2, X$ are topological spaces:

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X_0 @>{}>> X_1\\ @V{}VV @VV{}V\\ X_2 @>>{}> X\end{CD}$$

Now let $K$ be a compact space. How do we show that the following diagram is a pushout?

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X_0 \times K @>{}>> X_1\times K\\ @V{}VV @VV{}V\\ X_2\times K @>>{}> X\times K\end{CD}$$

My attempt was to simply let $k \in K$ be arbitrary and use the universal property of pushouts for each $k$, but then we would have difficulty in showing the continuity of such function.

Any solutions/hints would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what "such a function" refers to in "we would have difficulty in showing the continuity of such function". Anyway, do you know how to construct (at the point-set level) the pushout of a span $A \leftarrow B \to C$ in the category of topological spaces?

Comment: Alternatively – but this requires some more advanced point set topology – you could show that ${-} \times K$ has a right adjoint.

Comment: The result can be weakened; the product with a locally compact space already preserves pushouts as proven in Corollary 2.1.3. in this script: https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/mweis_02/lehre/TopologieWS18-19/top2_skriptWS18.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in response to a request for a less categorical viewpoint. It was hard work but I learnt a lot about the rigorous justification for the categorical viewpoint from [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/StricklandCGHWSpaces.pdf) paper.

In the comments I said that it follows from the observation that, if $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map then $q\times1:X\times K\to Y\times K$ is also a quotient map. Unfortunately I can no longer remember if this is true for *all* compact spaces $K$ or just for the compact **Hausdorff** ones. I do not have my notes to hand and a brief online search has failed to clarify. As I alluded to in the comments, there is a serious issue of terminology here. Many authors seem to feel it is a good idea to let "compact" describe a "compact *Hausdorff*" space which muddies the waters (I think this is what historically happened and tradition has preserved this convention). Moreover, we know this is true when $K$ is locally compact *if you take locally compact to mean* **strongly** locally compact (every point has a neighbourhood basis of compact sets) rather than weakly locally compact (every point has a compact neighbourhood).

Compact spaces are always weakly locally compact, but not necessarily strongly locally compact. But compact Hausdorff spaces are always locally compact in the strong sense. Anyway... here is a [reference](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf) for the fact that quotient maps are preserved by products with *strongly* locally compact spaces. Go to section $4.3$. The [author](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28586/ronnie-brown) there refers to quotient maps as "identification maps". For other terminology they use, just scroll up a little bit.

With that out of the way, in your diagram $X$ is (homeomorphic to) the quotient space: $$(X_1\sqcup X_2)/R$$Where $R$ is the equivalence relation generated by $x\sim y$ if there is $a\in X_0$ with $x=f(a)$ and $y=g(a)$, calling the top horizontal arrow $f$ and the left vertical arrow $g$. The arrows $X_{1,2}\to X$ are given by the compositions $X_{1,2}\hookrightarrow X_1\sqcup X_2\overset{q}{\twoheadrightarrow}(X_1\sqcup X_2)/R\cong X$. To check the second diagram is a pushout, you need to check that the diagram is still of that form. It's a good exercise to see why this construction makes a pushout if you don't already know. Hint: maps out of that quotient space correspond to certain types of map out of $X_1\sqcup X_2$, by the "universal property" of quotient maps. By our choice of $R$, such maps are exactly the same thing as maps which make $f$ agree with $g$.

$(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K\cong(X_1\sqcup K)\sqcup(X_2\times K)$ trivially and the relation $R$ is essentially unaffected since you're replacing $f$ with $f\times1$, $g$ with $g\times1$. Some thought shows that the only thing you actually need to check is whether or not: $$q\times 1:(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K\to X\times K$$Is a quotient map. If it is a quotient map, then it will be a quotient for the correct equivalence relation and the diagram will be a genuine pushout diagram (in $\mathsf{Top}$). If $K$ is strongly locally compact, then this is known to be true. I apologise for not currently remembering whether or not any old compact $K$ will suffice, but I imagine in your original use case $K$ would have been Hausdorff anyway. A very common example is $K=I$ the unit interval.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!

Comment: @hteica You’re welcome. I’ll get back to you when I can access my notes again, I would like to clarify whether or not this is known to be true/false for non-Hausdorff compact spaces.

Comment: I'm looking forward to that, thanks for taking the time

Comment: You said "$(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K\cong(X_1\sqcup K)\sqcup(X_2\times K)$" how to see this? I'm still a little bit confused with defining functions from an arbitrary set to a quotient space. Are we allowed to define a function in this manner? $f:(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K \rightarrow (X_1\sqcup K)\sqcup(X_2\times K)$, where $f(x,k) = (x,k)$? I personally doubt it, but then how would we define the homeomorphism?

Comment: @hteica your chosen $f$ is indeed the correct map and it is a homeomorphism too. Remember to get a continuous map out of a disjoint union space you just need a continuous map on each component. To get a continuous map *into* a product space, again, all you have to do is specify one map for each component. There is an obvious composite map $X_1\times K\to X_1\to X_1\sqcup X_2$ and $X_1\times K\to K$, these combine to a map $X_1\times K\to(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K$. Do the same for $X_2\times K$, together you get a continuous function: $$(X_1\times K)\sqcup(X_2\times K)\to(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K$$

Comment: It’s not too hard to check this is a homeomorphism. It also just sends a pair $(x,k)$ to $(x,k)$ loosely speaking (but it is not an identity function as the sets are technically different)

Comment: I can see that there is a continuous mapping $f:(X_1 \times K) \sqcup (X_2 \times K) \rightarrow (X_1 \sqcup X_2) \times K$ (exactly like how you just explained, using the universal properties), but the problem is always with the other direction since then we would have to prove the continuity of a function from a product space to a disjoint union space. How would we do this?

Comment: @hteica Let $f:(X_1\times K)\sqcup(X_2\times K)\to(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K$ be as discussed, for *arbitrary* spaces $X_1,X_2,K$. It is pretty clear that $f$ is a bijection, so to show it is a homeomorphism we need only show it is open (alternatively, you can show that $(X_1\times K)\sqcup(X_2\times K)$ has the same universal property that $(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K$ does). It suffices to show $f(U)$ is open when $U$ is an open subset of one of the unionands: it then suffices to show $f(A\times B)$ is open when $A\subseteq X_{1\text{ or }2}$ is open and $B\subseteq K$ is open.

Comment: But the image $f(A\times B)$ is "just" $A\times B$ in $(X_1\sqcup X_2)\times K$, which is clearly open since if $A$ is an open subset of one of $X_{1,2}$ it is an open subset of $X_1\sqcup X_2$. Done!

Comment: Thanks. That's a very straightforward way in showing the statement, I tried defining an inverse function $g$ to show its continuity but then I didn't know how to effectively show that $U \subset (X_1 \times K) \sqcup (X_2 \times K)$ open implies $g^{-1}(U)$ open. But arguing in your fashion without mentioning $g^{-1}$ at all seems to be much more elegant and effective!

Comment: But one question: why does it suffice to show that $f(U)$ is open for $U = A \times B$? We know that $U$ is of the form $U_1 \sqcup U_2$ where $U_{1,2} \subset X_{1,2} \times K$

Comment: Wait nevermind, I understand now, you simply rewrite $U_1$ as $A \times B$ and in the end we know that $f(U_1)$ and $f(U_2)$ are open, so $f(U) = f(U_1 \sqcup U_2)$ is open. Is this correct?

Comment: @hteica It's almost correct. It's not true that I can just rewrite $U_1$ as $A\times B$, *but* I know that $U_1$ is some union of sets of the form $A\times B$, so if I can show each of the $f(A\times B)$ are open then it follows $f(U_1)$ is also open because the property of being open is preserved by taking unions!

Comment: I see, you are absolutely right. Once again, thank you!

Comment: @hteica No problem!

Comment: @hteica Sorry to take so long to get back to you on this. If $K$ is compact then the situation is very subtle. $q\times 1$ is a quotient map in the sense that *it has the right universal property*... **if** you work in the category of $k$-spaces or compactly generated spaces (or similar). That also brings with it the following issue: products in this category are not quite topological products. They are the "$k$-ifications" of the ordinary topological product - this equals the usual product under certain conditions I don't recall right now. But it's not generally a quotient in the usual sense

Comment: Its ok, I appreciate the effort, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In general, the Cartesian monoidal category Top is not closed, since the functor $\_ \times A : Top \to Top$ doesn't preserve coequalizers for an arbitrary object $A$.

However, in the special case when $A = K$ is locally compact (and in particular, for compact), $\_ \times K$ has a right adjoint, namely $[K,\_] : Top \to Top$. For any space $Y$, $[K,Y]$ is the set of all continuous maps of $K$ into $Y$,  equipped with the compact open topology. The local compactness assumption on $K$ allows you to show that the map $ev_Y : [K,Y] \times K \to Y$ sending $(f, a) \mapsto f(a)$ is continuous. See
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact-open+topology
for a proof.

The map $ev_Y$ is clearly natural in $Y \in Top$. Further, the pair $([K, Y], ev_Y)$ will be a terminal object in the slice category $(\_ \times K \downarrow Y)$ for each $Y \in Top$ (this is the same proof as in the case of Set), so that you have an adjunction $\_ \times K \dashv [K,\_]$ as mentioned.

Finally, since $\_ \times K$ is a left adjoint, it will preserve pushouts, as already mentioned by Zhen Lin in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you provide an explanation without mentioning adjunctions etc? since I'm sadly still fairly unfamiliar with those terms, are there any elementary proofs?

Comment: Actually the relationship between compact and locally compact is a bit subtle (like it is for connected and locally connected). It depends on definitions.

Comment: @hteica a more elementary point-set argument can be used to show that, if $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map and $K$ is compact, then $q\times 1:X\times K\to Y\times K$ is a quotient map. Then because pushouts can be viewed as quotients, you're ok. The adjunction perspective is better because if you can remember under what conditions a space has these exponential right adjoints (compact, locally compact Hausdorff, and in a more subtle sense compactly generated spaces too) you can just look at a diagram and immediately know the colimit (which a pushout is) will be preserved by the product

Comment: And to elaborate on Zhen's comment, when researching definitions of compact and compactly generated and locally compact you need to watch out for: (1) is "compact" used in the old-fashioned sense, i.e. meaning compact *Hausdorff*? (2) are they talking about weakly locally compact (every point has a compact neighbourhood) or strongly locally compact (every point has a neighbourhood base of compact sets)? (3) what definition of compact is used when defining compactly generated? The definitions used do have implications on whether or not you genuinely have an exponential right adjoint

Comment: @FShrike thanks for the explanation, the problem is simply I'm not well acquainted yet with colimits and limits. could you elaborate how to the proof follows from showing that $q \times 1$ is a quotient map? Thanks

Comment: @FShrike and thank you for the comment, I'll make extra care in researching definitions of compact etc